# how to migrate data from one WSO2 Greg database schema to another schema?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

There are some data present in the Oracle database schema corresponding to few type of artifacts in WSO2 Greg version 4.6. Now I have changed WSO2 Greg version 5.3 connected to that database (New schema), where artifacts attributes(field) have been changed (Change the content in RXT file). How would I migrate that old data (for version 4.6) from one schema to another schema?

Note: The data gets stored into database in BLOB format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to migrate data from one version to the next immediate version and continue that up to the latest version.

You can follow [this migration doc of 5.3.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release).